# Form to submit file to controller upload action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controller:

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
    .
    .
    .

    def upload
    bucket = find_bucket
    file = params[:file] edit: previously was file = :file
    if bucket           
        AWS::S3::S3Object.store(file, open(file), bucket)
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render text: "Couldn't upload"
    end
end  


    private

    .
    .
    .

    def find_bucket
    AWS::S3::Bucket.find('kanesmusic')
end                     
end
```

Upload form in index view:

```
<h2>Upload a new MP3:</h2>  

<%= form_tag upload_path, :method => "post", :multipart => true do %>  
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>  
    <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>  
<% end %>
```

Error (edited):

`TypeError in SongsController#upload...can't convert AWS::S3::Bucket into String`

I'm trying to create this form that can select a file from a users hard drive and upload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use params. That where all the vars are stored.

Like so:

```
  params[:file]
```

But for using **file upload**  (thats slightly different) have a look at the docs

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: Oh yes. When I do this I now get the error `TypeError in SongsController#upload...can't convert AWS::S3::Bucket into String`. Any ideas?

Comment: which gem your using?

Comment: that one uses a reference to the file on *disk*. you nee to send the temp. filename for uploading. I think: params[:file].tempfile.path (you can inspect params[:file].inspect to your log)

Comment: Thanks @Rogier. This does allow the file to be uploaded however name of the uploaded file becomes `tmp/RackMultipart20130901-12859-vi2uhm` instead of the proper file name. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Great! Well if i look @ http://amazon.rubyforge.org [S3Object.store(file, open(file), 'jukebox')], name is the first parameter, the second the file handle. Maybe you can change that, so you have a readable filename?

Comment: In case anybody in the future reads this I solved the naming problem by putting `file = params[:file]` and then underneath the `if bucket` statement I put `AWS::S3::S3Object.store(file.original_name, file.read, bucket)`. Thanks again for the help Rogier.